# PyDev doesn't autocomplete for some modules (numpy, matplotlib at least)

Tags: python, pydev

This is similar, but not this question [Code-Completion for e.g. Numpy, SciPy or Matplotlib does not work in Eclipse PyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593472/code-completion-for-e-g-numpy-scipy-or-matplotlib-does-not-work-in-eclipse-pyd)

My problem isn't that PyDev can't resolve the variables as their specific type, I can't even get it to look into the numpy module for the functions.  For example

```
import numpy as np
np.<ctrl+space>
```

gives me nothing.  These modules are in my list of forced builtins.

Autocomplete does work for many other modules (including Qt/qwt, serial, struct)  and the programs run fine.  However, every time I use np.something eclipse thinks it is an error(red line under it).  Does this "just work" for everyone else?

Edit (additional info):

There are errors in my error log.  However, they are about Java not having permissions to run pylint and complaints about invalid encoding.  I am running Eclipse 3.8.1 with python 2.7 on Ubuntu 13.04.  Historically, I develop python in Spyder, so whatever I am missing likely has to do with Elipse nuances.

Answer (score 5):

It should 'just work' for you. Can you check if 'numpy' is on the 'forced builtins' list (in your interpreter configuration -- it should be added automatically, but it's possible it's not there. See: http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html for details on it).

If it is and you still have an issue, please check if you have some error in your error log -- see: http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F for details on getting it.

Comment: Yes, it is listed in my builtins.  In fact, if I remove it from that list it actually works a little better.  As in, it can now give some suggestions when I type np.<ctrl_space>.  However, it doesn't find all the things normally associated with a numpy import (array for example is missing).

Comment: Also, thanks for your work on PyDev.  On first inspection, it seems very powerful.